# Is iphone app for sale worldwide when uploading?

Tags: ios, app-store

I don't remember an option to choose where I would like my app to be for sale, but my question is:

#### If I made my app free and have submit it, would people be able to download it worldwide?

I have found the section to allow different countries to download the app, but I just want to make sure.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. 

Comment: Ok I just re-read the rules again, I'm new to this and I thought this was a practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession.

Comment: @AsL For future reference, this question is better suited for Apple's developer forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

By default, all territories are selected when uploading the first version of an app.

Comment: Thank you Very much :) I found the page earlier and noticed all the countries were selected but wasn't sure if I should save it because it could slow down the review process anyways, thx again